# Hypothesis of probit model

Tags: stata, assumptions, probit

1. I would like to know if we need to test the assumption of residuals' normality when we have probit model? And if this assumption is violated how can I correct it with Stata?
2. In the case of Probit model, how can I calculate the pearson matrix using Stata?

Comment: Be aware that CV is not a statistical software support site. Your question about the probit is on-topic, but Stata code may not come with the answer.

Comment: How do you define the residuals in a probit model?

Answer (score 1):

1) Probit is part of family of generalized linear models (GLM). You can use deviance as a analysis of model fit.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deviance_(statistics)

2) Do you mean covariance of regressors? If that is so then you need an information matrix..

Comment: Thank you for your answers. But i did not understand why i must use deviance. You said that probit is part of GLM, so it is necessary to test for normality. Regarding my second question I mean the "pairwise correlation", how can i calculate it for probit model using stata? Tahnk you

Comment: @Rourou29 There is no residuals in least squares sense. Deviance is only statistic which act as one in GLM setting. Normal distribution is part of the picture only because your link function is probit. I do not understand what you mean by pairwise correlation. Do you mean between two regressors or what?

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes I mean between two regressors.

Comment: @Rourou29 you need an covariance matrix of regressors. Here is link to function http://www.stata.com/manuals13/pmatrixget.pdf

Comment: @Rourou29 You are welcome. Perhaps you can select my answer as the best one? :)

Answer (score 0):

The typical use of a probit model is in predicting a probability. As probabilities are restricted to the interval $[0,1]$ and normal distributions can take any real number, there is no theoretical basis for wanting normal residuals.